# How to validate floating point numbers through regex and get it in the float type field?

Tags: c#, regex

In the following code regex behaves perfectly fine when used with string field but ToString and float.parse methods or  convert.ToString and convert.ToSingle makes  regex behavior unexpected.

```
public float ProductPrice
{
    get => _productPrice;
    set
    {

        var regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.?[0-9]{1,2})?\S$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("incorrect pattern");
        _productPrice = value;
        MessageBox.Show(_productPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
}

// calling area

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var product = new Product(){ProductPrice = float.Parse(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) };
        // product.ProductPrice = float.Parse(product.ValidatingFloatValue(textBox1.Text));

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Before looking at the code to answer, I would advise against a message box in your property's set code

Comment: After another look at the code, if your property's type is `float`, you won't need to validate using regex because if it got there, the compiler is happy that it is a floating point number. If you want to validate it's range then you'll need to use a differnet method of validation

Comment: In addition to what everyone else has said, if you did have a string (rather than a float, like you do), a much easier (and much less error-prone) way of validating that a string does represent a valid float is `float.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an issue when trying to give the property a value in your button click event handler try doing the following...

```
try
{
    float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out float value);
    var product = new Product()
    {
        ProductPrice = value
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This way if it is an invalid number in the text box, you will pass the default. Alternatively, you can test for a zero before passing it and display a message to the user to correct the input or you can pass a reasonable default.

See also the Overload of `TryParse` that takes some `NumberStyles` like whether you allow digit separators, currency symbol etc. (I didn't know what you're validating so opted against this one) and allows you to specify the culture as you have in your example.

Comment: how can I get the desired precision floating point value, like I want only two digits after decimal point and if user enters more than two digits, program should automatically round it to two.

Comment: @AliRasheed typically you want to work with your numeric values as is and any rounding should be done when displaying. You'll have to use one of the formatted output options such as `string.Format()` or string concatenation as follows `$"{product.ProductPrice:N2}"`. The N2 option means to format the output as a general number with 2 digits after the decimal point. Leaving it as N has the same effect but I like to explicitly state how many digits should be there. It will do the necessary rounding to match your precision.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `regex` to validate that `value` is a `float`, since it's guaranteed to be that type already (otherwise the caller would get a compile time error). Since that is apparently the *only* validation being done, you can get rid of the `_productPrice` backing field and then property can just be:

```
public float ProductPrice { get; set; }
```

In your click event, you can avoid using `try` / `catch` for error handling by using the [`float.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float temp;

    if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out temp))
    {
        var product = new Product { ProductPrice = temp };
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number and try again");
    }
}
```

Note that as your code currently stands, the click event doesn't do anything = `product` goes out of scope before it does anything meaningful.